# Regex Java - how to check if comma character does not exists between values?

Tags: java, regex, datetime-format

For given String I would like to check if between any number and any literal character exists comma separator and only in this order.

Example:
`Mo-Do 10:00-20:00 Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00`

should give me true / false if `,` exists between `20:00Fr-Sa`. Before parsing I always remove whitespaces.

Comment: ".*\\d[A-Za-z].*"

Comment: Why not create a pattern for Mo-Do 10:00-20:00 and extract only that part and ignore whether there is a comma or not.

Comment: Please explain why it’s worth knowing whether there’s a comma there. Asking because this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and we’d like to help you with your *real* problem.

Comment: In case of `Mo-Fr 10:00-20:00(,) Sa 10:00-17:00(,) So 12:00-14:00`, do you care whether the comma is after 20, after 17 or in both places?

Answer (score 1):

```
String withComma = "Mo-Do 10:00-20:00, Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00".replace(" ", "");
String withoutComma = "Mo-Do 10:00-20:00 Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00".replace(" ", "");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\d,[A-Z].*");

System.out.println(pattern.matcher(withComma).matches()); //true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(withoutComma).matches()); //false
```

Returns `true` if input string contains any number of characters followed by (in this order)

1. a digit `\\d`
2. a comma `,`
3. a capital letter `[A-Z]`
4. any number of characters `.*`

Comment: This solution does not match correctly situation when there are the same opening hours everyday `Mo-Sa 10:00-20:00`, I had to a little bit change this and use regex `".*\\d[A-Za-z].*"` which @Ralf Renz sent me in comment.

Comment: `[A-Za-z]` means day name can begin with either lower or uppercase character. I don't see how this is relevant in the context of same opening hours everyday as there shouldn't be any match possible in that scenario.

Comment: I mean to use regex wthout comma inside instead with comma. And then reverse if() statement. Simplyfying, your solution is working correctly if using `".*\\d[A-Z].*"` or `".*\\d[A-Za-z].*"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned regex to check the existence of the mentioned pattern.

```
String input = "Mo-Do 10:00-20:00 Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00";

String inputWithoutWhiteSpace = input.replaceAll("\\s", "");

String pattern = "(.*)([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[A-Z][a-z]-[A-Z][a-z])(.*)";

boolean patternExist = inputWithoutWhiteSpace.matches(pattern);
```

Comment: hi, the situation is a little more complex because I can also have string for different opening hours during the same day `"Mo-Do 08:00-12:00 & 13:00-20:00 Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00"`. I just didn't add all possibilities which I can have because the most important was to check if comma separator exists between number string and alphabet character.

Comment: The above pattern is  working  correctly for the given  scenario. "Mo-Do 08:00-12:00 & 13:00-20:00 Fr-Sa 10:00-21:00"